# Save read-only workbook without dialog box

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks; one is a user interface and the other a database. When the interface is opened, the data from the database is automatically loaded. The user can now add and edit data in the interface. When saved, all changes will be transmitted to the database and the interface will be cleared from all entries.

Reason: Multiple users have to work on the same database at the same time but not the exact same data, i.e. one user works on car-data and one on motorcycle-data, and all information has to be in the same database.

I want the users to open the interface in read-only, because they would have to anyway whenever more than one works with the interface. No problem so far.

But when the user wants to save the data, he get's the warning dialog that he cannot save the workbook because it is in read-only and he has to pick a location where he can save a copy. If he chooses a location, my macro runs normal and transmitts all changes to the database. The user can now cancel the save process and everything is ok.

But!
I want to interrupt this dialog (because the interface isn't saved anyway). But any code in "Workbook_BeforeSave" will run AFTER the user is prompted to pick a location for the copy.

Tried this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Cancel = True
    If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then
        Code to save data to database
    End if
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

But as mentioned, that runs AFTER the dialog box.

Comment: Give the user a "Save Workbook" button and handle it there?

Comment: @TimWilliams Hm... can i deactivate the normal save button?

Comment: Maybe start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Excel+disable+save+button   I've never done it myself.